# Facebook-like "time since" calculation algorithm

Tags: facebook, algorithm, timestamp

On Facebook, each comment or other user event has a timestamp. But it is not listed as a simple date, but presented in a form of a human-friendly string. For example if right now it is 08:38 and the comment was made at 08:31, Facebook doesn't just tell you the time, but says "7 minutes ago".

Is there an open source implementation of Facebook algorithm (or similar) that takes a data of event, a current date and tells in a human-friendly form how long has it been since?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dig into [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) jQuery plugin's [source code](https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/blob/master/jquery.timeago.js) to study.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty date http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-pretty-date/ is a good javascript library for this

Answer (score 0):

What I think that should be the best is this :

1. Store the timestamp when the comment is made (eg- 3:45 12-10-2012)
2. Get the current system time
3. Get the differnce between the two .i.e (current time -comment time ) .

Most of the languages provide the datediff method . Like in PHP you can use it like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)